# how use php namespace with customize_register?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to use PHP namespace while registering a customizer function in wordpress, my filename is 'customizer.php' that is included in functions.php. I uploading logo by customizer and it gives following error

"Fatal error: Class 'Roots\Sage\Customizer\WP_Customize_Upload_Control' not found in customizer.php"

This is code I am using.

```
namespace Roots\Sage\Customizer;
add_action('customize_register',__NAMESPACE__.'\\sageCustomizeRegister');
function sageCustomizeRegister( $wp_customize ) {

$wp_customize->add_setting( 'site_logo', [
        'type' => 'theme_mod',
        'default' => NULL,
] );

$wp_customize->add_control( 
    new WP_Customize_Upload_Control( 
    $wp_customize, 
    'site_logo', 
    [
            'label'      => __( 'Site Logo', 'sage' ),
            'section'    => 'title_tagline',
            'description' => 'Please upload site logo to show in header'
    ] ) 
);    

}
```

Please guide me what to do to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 4):

The issue you have is with this line:

```
new WP_Customize_Upload_Control(
```

The namespace at the top of your file means you're instantiating a non-existent class. It's the equivalent of:

```
new \Roots\Sage\Customizer\WP_Customize_Upload_Control(
```

You need to refer to the class in the global space. Simply prefix the class you're calling with a backslash.

```
new \WP_Customize_Upload_Control(
```

Further reading: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php